# Angular RouterReuseStrategy, how to reuse only from specific routes?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have `RouterReuseStrategy` in place for my application, that looks like below

```
import {
    RouteReuseStrategy,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    DetachedRouteHandle,
} from '@angular/router';


export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

    /**
     * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later
     */
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        if (!route.routeConfig || route.routeConfig.loadChildren) {
            return false;
        }
        /** Whether this route should be re used or not */
        let shouldReuse = false;
        if (route.routeConfig.data) {
            route.routeConfig.data.reuse ? shouldReuse = true : shouldReuse = false;
        }
        //Check the from route and decide whether to reuse or not
        if(route.routeConfig.path == 'page1') {
            shouldReuse = false;
        } else {
            shouldReuse = true;
        }
        return shouldReuse;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the detached route.
     */
    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handler: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        console.log('[router-reuse] storing handler');
        if (handler) {
            this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)] = handler;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be reattached
     * @param route Stores the detached route.
     */
    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the previously stored route
     */
    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        if (!route.routeConfig || route.routeConfig.loadChildren) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a route should be reused
     */
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        /** We only want to reuse the route if the data of the route config contains a reuse true boolean */
        let reUseUrl = false;

        if (future.routeConfig) {
            if (future.routeConfig.data) {
                reUseUrl = future.routeConfig.data.reuse;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Default reuse strategy by angular assers based on the following condition
         * @see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.6/packages/router/src/route_reuse_strategy.ts#L67
         */
        const defaultReuse = (future.routeConfig === current.routeConfig);

        // If either of our reuseUrl and default Url are true, we want to reuse the route
        //
        return reUseUrl || defaultReuse;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a url for the current route
     */
    getUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        /** The url we are going to return */
        let next = route;
        // Since navigation is usually relative
        // we go down to find out the child to be shown.
        while (next.firstChild) {
          next = next.firstChild;
        }
        let segments = '';
        // Then build a unique key-path by going to the root.
        while (next) {
          segments += next.url.join('/');
          next = next.parent;
        }
        return segments;
    }
}
```

Route configuration in the module,

```
{ path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
{ path: 'page2', component: Page2Component , data: {reuse: true}},
{ path: 'page3', component: Page3Component },
```

As seen reuse is set to true for page2 component, I want the reuse to work in page2 component only when  I'm coming **from page3** to **page2** and **not** from **page1** to **page2**

I have made changes in `shouldDetach` method to check the from route and decide whether to detach or not. But this doesn't seem to work. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my route reuse setup I have another field called reuseRoutesFrom.  In my case I have a list and a detail so when navigating back to my list from a detail page I want to reuse the list, so for the list setup, I'll have something like this:

```
{
        path: '',
        component: ListComponent,
        data: {
            shouldReuseRoute: true,
            reuseRoutesFrom: ['Detail', 'Detail/:Id']
        }
    },
```

And in my route reuse strategy service I look at this in the should attach like this:

```
shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        var wasRoutePreviouslyDetached = !!this.handlers[route.url.join('/') || route.parent.url.join('/')];
        if (wasRoutePreviouslyDetached) {
            var reuseRouteFromVerified = route.data.reuseRoutesFrom.indexOf(this.routeLeftFrom) > -1;

            if (reuseRouteFromVerified) {

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When detaching, I cache the route that I left from as well to be used above:

```
    private routeLeftFrom: string;

    constructor() {}

    // Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
        this.routeLeftFrom = route.routeConfig.path;
        return route.data.shouldReuseRoute || false;
    }
```

Comment: Does this work ?  For me 'route.routeConfig.path' return empty  when i navigating back from the previous target to the page which i want to reuse

Comment: I'm on Angular 9 currently and this still works.  Can't say for sure for 10 and 11 yet.  Keep in mind I've only posted part of the route reuse service here since the original poster already had what looked to be working versions of the rest of it.